# Is there a way to print the Contents of a Specific DIV

Tags: javascript

I have a Pape width different DIVs and a PRINT link.
I want that if the user clicks on a Print link should 
a specific DIV be printed not the whole page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you can use CSS, like so:

```
@media print {
  body * {
    display:none;
  }

  #divToPrint {
    display:block;
  }
}
```

but I don't think this is supported on all browsers. The alternative would be to open the contents of the DIV in a new window, and then print that window.

Comment: Any reason you use specifiy the `body` tag?

Answer (score 0):

Use [print media stylesheets](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/goingtoprint/) to set everything else to `display: none` (you'll need to construct your markup in such a way that nothing you want to print is a descendent of something you do want to print).

Toggle class names on the div elements to select which ones get printed.